# How to display number of labels when input number? using javascript and html and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

i have got 1 input field(name="no_of_days") and 1 label(name="label_days") and the submit button. when input number of days and click 
submit button i want to display number of labels. 
**Eg:= no_of_days == 5 then
    display 5 labels
I want to use javascript and html and nodejs**

this is my try.. **but console.log("inside function"); is not coming to cmd.**
(my english is not good.I guess you can understand what i am say)

```
 //package1.handlebars
<form action="/users/package1" method="post">

<div id="container">
<input name="test" type="text"  >
<input value="add" type="submit"  onClick="add()">
</div>
//end package1.handlebars



//inside routes file > users.js
router.get('/package1', function(req, res) {
 res.render('package1');
});

router.post('/package1', function(req, res) {
 res.render('package1');
var i=0;
console.log(i);
function add(){    
  console.log("inside function");
    if (User.getElementById('test').value!='') 
    {   
        i++;  
        var title   =User.getElementById('test').value;
        var node = User.createElement('div');        
        node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="check' + i + '" name="check' + i + '"><label for="check' + i + '">'+ test +'</label>';       
      User.getElementById('container').appendChild(node);    
    }
}; 
});
```

Comment: You are interested in creating one label for every day? Or, you want to display the number of days in the label text? Or... something different?

Comment: I at least have no idea what you mean

Comment: @PeterAbolins neither. user input 10 and i want to display 10 labels.likewise.. please help me i want to do it today

Comment: @minseong user input 10 and i want to display 10 labels.likewise.  please help me i want to do it today

Comment: I am still very unsure what you are asking. Can you provide the code you have written? That would possibly shed some light on the issue. At the moment it looks like: `User enters the number 10, and submits. The page is filled with 10 labels which all are called 'label_days'`.

Comment: ya, that's right. i have .js file and .handlebars file

Comment: please re-check my question..i add my code

Comment: I haven't used `handlebars`, but there is something not right with your code. You have specified a form action, along with an input of type `submit`, as well as an `onclick` event action. I suspect that the `add()` function is never called, in favour of a straight `post` request. If `console.log(i);` is executed and shows up in the command console, then this would confirm my suspicion.

Comment: ya it's correct. add() function is never used. How to call add function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<label> no_of_days </label>

<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2" name="no_of_days">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">  Submit </button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {

         var label = "";

        var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;

        for(var i =1; i <= x; i++){

            label += "label day:" +i + "<br>";

        }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = label; 

    }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```